# javascript - repeat action at regular interval after onlick has been triggered

Tags: javascript, settimeout, setinterval

I have a div which is displayed with onclick then which disappear with setTimeout:

css

```
#light {
position:absolute;
left:40px;
top:45px;
border-left:50px solid transparent;
border-right:50px solid transparent;
border-bottom:20px solid red;
opacity:0;
}
```

js (don't know if the syntax is correct but it works)

```
function change() {
  var element = document.getElementById("light");
  element.style.opacity = "1";
  element.style.transitionDelay = "4s", // only the 1stime with onclick
    setTimeout(() => {
      element.style.opacity = "0";
    }, 5000)
}
```

html

```
<button onclick="change()">light</button>
<div id="light"></div>
```

What I would like is that this action repeats then by itself every 2 minutes:
- after 2min, #light is displayed again for 5s (opacity="1")
- then hidden again (opacity="0")
and so on, and so every 2 min.
I know about the setInterval() method but it's too difficult for me to use it correctly - the script doesn't work at regular interval (every 2 min).
ps: I've looked similar questions but all this is beyond my competence (ie, 0).

Comment: the only function i've seen even close to what you want with a timer uses recursion.  It basically is impossible.  Normally pages that have stuff like this that runs forever reload with parameters.

Comment: So basically it's impossible ? Or not recommended perhaps ?

Comment: Are you aware of event loop in Javascript?

Comment: I'm aware of nothing in javascript, doing stuff for fun only. It seems my request is not a good idea then ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you can't use timeouts?
Wouldn't something like this work?
( you can adjust the timers... I didn't want to wait minutes to see the light blink so I set it to few seconds)

```js
let timer;
let started = false;
let delayTimer;
const lightOn = (clicked) => {
  // do nothing if clicked for the second time
  if (clicked && started) {return;}
  const fn = () => {
    const element = document.getElementById("light");
    element.classList.add('light-on');
    timer = setTimeout(lightOff, 1000);
  };
  if (clicked) {
    delayTimer = setTimeout(fn, 3000);
  } else {
    fn();
  }
  started = true;
}
const lightOff = () => {
  const element = document.getElementById("light");
  element.classList.remove('light-on');
  timer = setTimeout(lightOn, 2000);
}
const stop = () => {
  clearTimeout(timer);
  clearTimeout(delayTimer);
  timer = undefined;
  delayTimer = undefined;
  started = false;
}
```

```css
.light {
  background-color: gray;
  opacity: 0.1;
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 2em;
}
.light-on {
  background-color: yellow;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="light" class="light"></div>
<button onclick="lightOn(true)" style="display: block;">start</button>
<button onclick="stop()" style="display: block;">stop</button>
```

Comment: I don't wan't a button onclick="stop()" function, just one button onclick="lighton()" to trigger the div (ie, #light is on), then #light is off with setTimeout and opacity="0" (this 1st part is ok for me, it works). After that, I'd like a loop to be executed by itself: after x seconds, make #light on again, then make it off again, etc, every 2 minutes. So only one button at the start to trigger the div (#light=on), then the loop would take care of the rest (repeat light on / light off every x seconds). But it seems it's not a good idea (according to the comments above), so I'm not sure anymore

Comment: @ene thats how it works. Once you click the start button the light will turn on for 3 seconds....then stays off for 6 seconds...then on for 3 and so on. I added the stop funciton just as an FYI, if you need to stop the endless cycle at some point.

Comment: Oh sorry, it's because I saw that button onclick="stop()" at first so I thought there was a misunderstanding. I haven't tested yet your code indeed, I'm gonna try it and see if it works for me. Thank you !

Comment: Ok, it works perfectly, this is exactly what I wanted, thanks ! The only catch (well for me) is that I have to place the script right under <button>, so in the body of the html otherwise it doesn't seem to work. So I can't obviously use it as an external .js file either. It's not a big deal, just that I would have preferred having it worked that way - but again,  IT IS OK (I'm not complaining..). TY

Comment: @ene You can use that script wherever you like. You just have to make sure that your page has finished loading before you try to get the element with "light" id.
E.g you could move the "const element = document.getElementById("light");" into the beginning of both lightOn and lightOff functions.

Comment: Ah ok, many thanks, it works now. However, I have another problem: I've noticed when I click several times on the Start button, the script resets, and the stop event (const stop) no longer works (light keeps blinking). How can I prevent this (make the Start button be in pause as long as the stop button hasn't been clicked) ?

Comment: Very cool ! Seems so easy for you.. I'm quite embarrased to ask again, just one very last thing if I may.. Would just like that the script starts with a delay (ie, wait 3 seconds before running the script each time Start is clicked). Is it possible ? The Start button won't start to reset again, as it did before ? I randomly tried to add light.style.transitionDelay = "3s"; but it's certainly not very logical to use it with the setTimeout event as the script doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Fantastic !! I wish I had your knowledge in JS.. It certainly is a great asset. Well I think I'm done for good.. Lucky you :) Thanks for your time and for helping Rainer, much appreciated.